# HTML5 validation in an auto generated Symfony2 form <select> field

Tags: html, symfony, w3c

I have the following code on a required select :

```
<select required="required">
    <option value="1">01</option>
    <option value="2">02</option>
    ...
    <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
```

In my (HTML5 / symfony2) app its a required date (day) so the value must be between 1 and 31 and I do not want blank/null values.

Even though the code works, it breaks w3c validation with the following error :

> The first child option element of a select element with a required
>   attribute and without a multiple attribute, and whose size is 1, must
>   have either an empty value attribute, or must have no text content.

What is the best approach to the problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `require` attribute:

```
<select required="required">
<option value=""></option><!-- added empty value -->
<option value="1">01</option>
<option value="2">02</option>
...
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>
```

Without – just remove `require` attribute:

```
<select>
<option value="1">01</option>
<option value="2">02</option>
...
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If you don't want to include the blank option another way you can do this is by setting the `selectedIndex` of the `<select>` to `-1`.

Comment: Right, but I don't know if it pass the w3c validator. It's JS solution and in fact empty `option` value (mentioned by validator) will still be missing. Needs test.

Comment: It'll pass the validator, but I agree that the empty `<option>` is the better solution.  I was just throwing it out there that it *will* work.